# Shell Script - Counting delimiters in a record from CSV file

Tags: shell

Through the shell program, I am reading a specific record (more than 100 columns) from.CSV file and counting the delimiters (,) by matching with each character in the record

I am matching reading each character stored in a string and comparing with char (,) to increment the count as below

```
for i in $(seq 0 ${#recordString})
if [ "${recordString:$i:1}" == "$char" ]
```

I want to understand how can I ignore delimiters (,) in double quotes while counting

**Solved the problem with below**

```
for i in $(seq 0 ${#recordString})
do
        if [ "${recordString:$i:1}" == "$dqchar" ]
        then
                dqcount=$((dqcount+1))
        fi
        if [ "${recordString:$i:1}" == "$char" ]
        then
        if [ $(( $dqcount % 2)) -eq 0 ]
                then
                        delCount=$((delCount+1))
                        echo $delCount
                fi
                if [ $i == $cmpPos ]
                then
                        break
                fi
        fi
done
```

Comment: Use a tool that actually understands the CSV format for starters. What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: my requirement - I get the byte position from a process which I use to break out of the "for" loop when i equals position. By this I want to count the delimiters within the position and evaluate the column and drop the column in the next step

Comment: If you want to remove columns, look into csvcut from the csvkit project. It has lots of useful programs for manipulating CSV files.

Comment: I am able to drop the column !! have issue with ignoring the delimiter within double quotes

Comment: That's why you use a tool that understands the format instead of trying to hack something together.

Comment: I have solved my problem - thank you !!